# How to search for a string like \x60\xe2\x4b(indicating a emoticon) using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, emoticons

```
import re

string="b'@DerkGently @seanferg85 @Umbertobaggio @EL4JC and he already had Popular support.. most people know this already. A\xe2\x80\xa6 '"

print(re.findall(r"\x[0-9a-z]{2}",string))
```

## The the list returned by the findall() function is empty :(

Comment: Can you please edit your code or add an expected result?

Comment: How did you get that string? It seems like a python representation of a `bytes` object has been copy/pasted and quotes put around it to make a string. Those `\xe2\x80\xa6` are treated a string escapes and the \x isn't really there as a separate character. For instance `len("\xe2\x80\xa6`")` is 3 - its there is no slash x to look for.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your string is the Python representation of a Python `bytes` object, which is pretty much useless.

Most likely, you had a `bytes` object, like this:

```
b = b'@DerkGently @seanferg85 @Umbertobaggio @EL4JC and he already had Popular support.. most people know this already. A\xe2\x80\xa6 '
```

… and you converted it to a string, like this:

```
s = str(b)
```

Don't do that. Instead, decode it:

```
s = b.decode('utf-8')
```

That will get you the actual characters, which you can then match easily, instead of trying to match the characters in the string representation of the bytes representation and then reconstructing the actual characters laboriously from the results.

However, it's worth noting that `\xe2\x80\xa6` is not an emoji, it's a horizontal ellipsis character, `…`. If that isn't what you wanted, you already corrupted the data before this point.

Answer (score 0):

Not a regexp *per se*, but might help you out any way.

```
def emojis(s):
    return [c for c in s if ord(c) in range(0x1F600, 0x1F64F)]

print(emojis("hello world "))  # sample usage
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `re.compile(ur'A\xe2\x80\xa6',re.UNICODE)`

Compile a Unicode regex and use that pattern matching for your find,find all’s,subs,etc.

Comment: Unless he's on Python 2, his string and pattern are both already Unicode, and therefore UNICODE mode is already on. And even if he's on Python 2, this probably won't solve his problem.

Comment: @abarnert i didn’t know that. I was just browsing along and this is what came up. I look forward to seeing the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I joined the string in your question with that in your title to make the final search string

```
import re

k = r"@DerkGently @seanferg85 @Umbertobaggio @EL4JC and he already had Popular support.. most people know this already. A\xe2\x80\xa6 for a string like \x60\xe2\x4b(indicating a emoticon) using regular expression in python"
print(k)
print()
p = re.findall(r"((\\x[a-z0-9]{1,}){1,})", k)
for each in p:
    print(each[0])
```

Output

```
@DerkGently @seanferg85 @Umbertobaggio @EL4JC and he already had Popular support.. most people know this already. A\xe2\x80\xa6 for a string like \x60\xe2\x4b(indicating a emoticon) using regular expression in python

\xe2\x80\xa6
\x60\xe2\x4b
```

Comment: Thanx that was very helpful :)

Comment: @Biswadeep Roy thanks. But try accepting any of the posted answer that works for you.